# Last login details of a user

Tags: java, mysql

This is the query I am using

```
ResultSet rsta3=st.executeQuery("Select * FROM login_details WHERE name ='"+name1+"' AND intime = (select max(intime) from login_details where name = '"+name1+"')");
```

With this I get the current login details.How to get the previous login details?What query should I use?

[image]

The query given in the below answers gives only 11.44 time

Comment: Learn about prepared statements. To avoid SQL injection attacks, and to avoid a failure if the name is `O'Reilly`.

Comment: Please provide full information what you want? So, we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
Select * FROM login_details WHERE name ='"+name1+"' order by intime desc LIMIT 1,1
```

this should retrieve the second oldest record

Also as mentioned due to subsequent findings, as your DB is incorrectly storing your Date data as Varchar, your can use the below query until your fix your DB.

```
Select * FROM login_details WHERE name ='"+name1+"' order by id desc LIMIT 1,1
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but you'd better use `LIMIT 1, 1` and read the unique result.

Comment: @Vidic what do you mean?

Comment: it just gave me the 4th record from my table

Comment: maybe the times were the same?

Comment: I have logged in logged out so many times but gives the same time

Comment: Based upon your data, the 4th record should be returned as your are selecting by user.

Comment: So what should i do then?it should be 1.15 na?

Comment: I want to get 1.15 as the last login na?

Comment: I live in India,here its afternoon now.so the format going wrong I guess.this is the format i used String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";

Comment: In that case `Select * FROM login_details WHERE name ='"+name1+"' order by id desc LIMIT 1,1`  assuming that login records are added realtime

Answer (score 4):

You find by this

```
Select * FROM login_details WHERE name ='"+name1+"' order by intime desc LIMIT 1,1
```

Comment: I mean it gave me the wrong record.to be precise the 4th record

Comment: @Vidic: we can't help you if you don't provide details. Tell us what you have in your database, and what the query returns. Example input and output.

Comment: @Vidic: The result is correct. 11:44 is the previous to last login details for Jerry.

Comment: it should be 1.15 na?

Comment: 1:15 is 1:15 in the morning. 1:15 is before 11:44. 13:15 would be after 11:44.

Comment: I live in India,here its afternoon now.so the format going wrong I guess.this is the format i used String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";

Comment: @Vidic: The date in the database should be stored as a DATE, not as a VARCHAR. Use the right data type, and everything will go fine. The matter is even worse because you chose a format that could mean two different things. There is no way to distinguish 1:44 AM from 1:44 PM with the format you chose. Since the column is a varchar, it's sorted in lexicographic order, and not in chronological order.

Answer (score 0):

```
ResultSet rsta3=st.executeQuery("Select * FROM login_details WHERE name ='"+name1+"' AND intime = (select max(intime) from login_details where name = '"+name1+"' order by intime desc limit 1,1)");
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Your Query is right, but you are fetching the data after inserting the current login session.

So, once you validate your for user name and password, get the last login details using your query and then update your table with new login time.

Even the fetching with ORDER BY LIMIT should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

Select * from login_details where name = '"+name+"' order by outtime desc limit 1,1.

The sole idea is firstly sort the list in descending order by time which in your case is : (outtime) will display the result in the order you want. Then using limit fetch only the first record .